# How do I implement an auto-login with Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

We currently have an application with Spring Security and a login page. We're now able to retrieve the user info from the session, so we want to get rid of the login page to allow the user to auto-login.  I've been spinning my wheels on this for a week or two and don't know how to approach this with best Spring practices in mind.  Also, once the user has been authenticated they will be redirected to the appropriate page based on their roles.

Should I be using a filter, custom authentication provider, custom authentication manager and/or custom authentication entry point?

So we're using kerberos with Active Directory and we can retrieve the user info like this:

```
subject = Security.getCurrentSubject();
if ((subject != null) && (!SubjectUtils.isUserAnonymous(subject))) {
    Set principalSet = subject.getPrincipals();
    Principal[] principals = (Principal[]) principalSet.toArray(new Principal[0]);
    if ((principals != null) && (principals.length > 0)) {
        UserContext.get().pushSubject(subject);
    }
}
```

Here's the current spring-security.xml file.

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/includes/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/index**" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/error**" access="permitAll"/>

    <intercept-url pattern="/searchDist/fetchDocument**"
                   access="hasAnyRole('EED_SOC','EEConsumers','EEDocumentControllers')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/searchGT/fetchDocument**"
                   access="hasAnyRole('EEG_SOC','EET_SOC','EEDocumentControllers')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/searchDist**" access="hasAnyRole('EED_SOC','EEConsumers','EEDocumentControllers')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/searchGT**" access="hasAnyRole('EEG_SOC','EET_SOC','EEDocumentControllers')"/>

    <access-denied-handler error-page="/error"/>

    <form-login
            login-page="/index.html"
            default-target-url="/index.html"
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password"
            authentication-failure-url="/index.html"
            always-use-default-target="false"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationHandler"/>

    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/index.html"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: What is your current spring configuration, which authentication provider you have. Please provide more information.

Comment: What do you mean by 'autologin'?

Comment: Did you mean Single-Sign-on(SSO)? Refer http://www.baeldung.com/sso-spring-security-oauth2

Comment: Okay, I've added a bit of code. I don't really think it's single sign-on because the user never puts in their username and password.

Comment: Please help. I'm really stumped on this one. Do you need any more information?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I'm almost where I want to be. I managed to find most of my answers by following this: http://javadiscover.blogspot.ca/2015/05/spring-security-pre-authentication.html